# How to type double \\?

Tags: symbols

I am trying to type:

```
C:\\Users\\Reymi\\Downloads\\imagen.png
```

all in one line. The problem is that because of `\\` it skips a line between each word.

Comment: `\textbackslash` makes `\ ` but usually `\verb|c:\Users\Reymi\Downloads\imagen.png|` is easier or  `\verb|c:\\Users\\Reymi\\Downloads\\imagen.png|` if you need `\\ `

Comment: @Werner That's not a symbol question but verbatim input.

Comment: @percusse: As it stands, the question is about the symbol, not setting a URL or other verbatim content.

Comment: @Werner It explicitly says "I want to write this in single line".

Comment: @percusse: It also explicitly asks "How to type double ``\\``?"

Comment: @Werner Nevermind

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`url`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/url) package for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}

\DeclareUrlCommand\file{%
    % Set monospace font
    \def\UrlFont{\ttfamily}%
    % Set characters to break after but not in between
    \def\UrlBigBreaks{\do\:\do\\}
}

\begin{document}

\file|C:\\Users\\Reymi\\Downloads\\imagen.png|

Here's some long sentence that shows that the path \file|C:\\Users\\Reymi\\Downloads\\imagen.png| is also broken across lines.

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]